# Table layout grouping

Tags: java, android, eclipse, checkbox, tablelayout

I am using table layout and my code is below. I need help for grouping rows together to a check box.

Second problem, I need help in passing a selected checkbox to another page.

Third, I need help in putting the button at bottom, so that is will not be covered and need to be scroll to find it.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#E7FEFF" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FFFFF0"
                android:text="Opp SAFRA Tampines"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:width="1000dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" >

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  5"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text02"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:checked="false" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:25   15:36    15:47"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:stretchColumns="2"
                android:text="  8"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Tampines Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:checked="false" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:26   15:27    15:36"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:stretchColumns="2"
                android:text="  15"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Tampines Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:checked="false" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:23   15:28    15:30"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:stretchColumns="2"
                android:text="  18"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Tampines Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:checked="false" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:30   15:31    15:34"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:stretchColumns="2"
                android:text="  21"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:checked="false" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:23   15:26    15:39"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/next" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try making a shorter example, this looks quite long

Comment: There are TABs in the ***text/string*** part in these three lines: "`android:text=" 5"`", "`android:text=" Pasir Ris Int"`", and "`android:text=" 15:25  15:36  15:47"`". Is that deliberate?

Comment: That is just to make the layout look nicer @PeterMortensen

Comment: sorry this is my code, its just 3 line of text and a check box repeated. done editing to half @cello

Comment: Sorry but what the difference that you just edited ?? @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: If you want the check box in the same row as something else, contain them both in the same

```
<TableRow>
```

element.

Problem 2: When passing information to a new activity use putExtra to pass it and getExtra in the new activity.

Problem 3: If you want your button to be at the bottom, in your XML file try

```
<android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

This would all be easier if you were to use a relative layout with linear layouts within it. Hope this helps!

Comment: hi, thanks for helping. do you know how to set button on the left and image button on the right in table row ??

Comment: I think this might help you http://sandipchitale.blogspot.ie/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html